# Star Wars TIE/LN Fighter, what does 'LN' stand for?

Tags: star-wars

Even Wookiepedia doesn't seem to have this information about the TIE Fighter from Star Wars.
The original TIE Fighter's full model name is TIE/LN.
A friend of mine insists it's "Tie-in".  But no. I've always known it to be L not I.  Wookiepedia also has it as LN, but no explanation as to what that last part stands for.

Does anyone know?

Comment: The TIE/In is the model number for the TIE Interceptor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **LN** model letters you've mentioned were an invention of the [Star Wars Essential Guide to Warfare](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Guide_to_Warfare) and seem to stands for **Tie/Line Fighter**; where "Line" indicates that it is the *production-line* model, one without any substantial modification (e.g. standing apart from the **TIE/IN** (TIE/Interceptor) and **TIE/AD** (TIE/Advanced Model), etc.).

[image]